# How to use service account to deploy objects(deployments, configmaps etc) in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, service-accounts, azure-devops, microk8s

I have a deploy-pipeline in Azure devops. I am using this to deploy some objects to our k8s cluster (microk8s). I connect to the cluster with the help of a service connection that uses a kube-config.

Now I want to move to using environments. But when using environments I can't use my service connection nor can I use a kube config, I have to use something called a service account.

I have tried adding a service account but it fails when trying to connect:

> Error from server (BadRequest): the server rejected our request for an
> unknown reason E0501 20:23:58.096274   11988 request.go:977]
> Unexpected error when reading response body: read tcp
> 10.53.225.240:63434->10.161.64.124:16443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I guess I haven't setup the service account correctly. Here is the yaml for the role, serviceaccount and rolebinding:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: app1serviceaccount
  namespace: elinstallation
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: elinstallation
  name: pod-creator
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-creator
  namespace: elinstallation
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: pod-creator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: app1serviceaccount
  namespace: elinstallation
```

Also created a secret for the service account:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: app1serviceaccount-secret
  namespace: elinstallation
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: app1serviceaccount
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

I then copy the output of this command:

> kubectl get secret app1serviceaccount-secret -n elinstallation -o
> json

And paste it into the secret field of the environment. Output looks something like this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "ca.crt": "LS0tLxxxxS0tLS0tCg==",
        "namespace": "ZWxpbnN0YWxsYXRpb24=",
        "token": "ZXlKaGJxxxxx"
    },
    "kind": "Secret",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Secret\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"kubernetes.io/service-account.name\":\"app1serviceaccount\"},\"name\":\"app1serviceaccount-secret\",\"namespace\":\"elinstallation\"},\"type\":\"kubernetes.io/service-account-token\"}\n",
            "kubernetes.io/service-account.name": "app1serviceaccount",
            "kubernetes.io/service-account.uid": "0b62b400-a0a9-4b27-822b-05d12b1c0930"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-04-30T07:11:53Z",
        "name": "app1serviceaccount-secret",
        "namespace": "elinstallation",
        "resourceVersion": "12050395",
        "uid": "f3b6d9d3-be29-4a85-9ee2-8fe72fca1dd2"
    },
    "type": "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
}
```

[image]

One thing that confuses me is that when typing this command:

```
kubectl get serviceAccounts -n elinstallation
NAME                            SECRETS   AGE
default                         0         3d10h
elinstallation-serviceaccount   0         37h
app1serviceaccount              0         36h
test                            0         8m46s
```

It says that no service account has a secret.

What am I doing wrong?

Sub question, is there somewhere in k8s (microk8s) where I can read access logs, to see more details to why I can't connect?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" You're not doing anything wrong as far as creating serviceaccounts and secrets: seeing a secret count of "0" is normal; that number only reflects secrets listed explicitly in the `secrets` section of a `serviceAccount` resource, which you normally only see for secrets that are created automatically (pre-Kubernetes-1.22 behavior).